# Filter Gravity Forms Entries by field value

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to echo out a list of Gravity Forms Entries, but only want to echo out the entries that have a certain value, within a certain field.

So for example, $entry['53'] is a field within the form that allows the user to select from a dropdown. There are only two options. Let's say A and B. How would I go about altering my code below to only show entries that have a value of B ?

The code I have at the moment is:

```
<?php
      //Get the Form ID to get the entries from and store it within a varibale

      $search_criteria = null;
        $sorting = null;
        $paging = null;

        $entries = GFAPI::get_entries( $form_id, $search_criteria, $sorting, $paging );

        echo '<ul>';
            foreach($entries as $entry) :
                echo '<li>Title: ' . $entry['2'] . '</li>';
            endforeach;
        echo '</ul>';
  ?>
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$search_criteria = array(
        'status'        => 'active',
        'field_filters' => array(
            array(
                'key'   => '53',
                'value' => 'B',
            ),
        )
    );
```

Comment: What if I don't know the key to this field but only the label?